# Vue 3 reactivity not triggered from inside a class instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

Codepen: https://codepen.io/codingkiwi_/pen/XWMBRpW

Lets say you have a class:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
    this.entries = ["a"];

    //=== example change triggered from INSIDE the class ===
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.entries.push("c");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

And in a component you get an instance of that class:

```js
const { reactive } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const myobject = reactive(new MyClass());

    //=== example change triggered from OUTSIDE the class ===
    setTimeout(() => {
      myobject.entries.push("b");
    }, 500);
    
    return {
      myobject
    };
  }
}
```

The myobject.entries array in the DOM will display the entries `"a"` and `"b"`, but not `"c"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The myobject.entries array in the DOM will display the entries `"a"` and `"b"`, but not `"c"`

This is because `"a"` was already in the array as we made the instance reactive and the push of `"b"` happened from outside the object, through the Proxy.

**To be clear**: the `const myobject` does not contain the `MyClass` instance, it contains a `Proxy` of the instance which handles/wraps the original instance! And it is the proxy which is passed to the DOM / Template.

The push of `"c"` happened from inside the object, **not** through the proxy. So `"c"` will be pushed to the array, but no reactivity change will be triggered.

## Fix:

Mark the array that we change from inside the class explicitly as `reactive` like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
    this.entries = reactive(["a"]);

    //=== example change triggered from INSIDE the class ===
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.entries.push("c");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Alternatively try to only work with the proxied object like the docs suggest:

> The best practice here is to never hold a reference to the original raw object and only work with the reactive version:

Docs: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#proxy-vs-original-identity

Answer (score 9):

As another answer explains, `reactive` creates proxy object to enable the reactivity. `this` in constructor refers to original `MyClass` instance and not a proxy, so it cannot cannot be reactive.

This indicates the probem in the code. `reactive` takes into account synchronous operations that occur in `MyClass` constructor. It's an antipattern to perform asynchronous side effects in a constructor , the reasons include possible implications with the code that consumes such constructor.

This can be solved with:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(){
    // synchronous stuff only
    this.entries = ["a"];
  }

  init() {
    // asynchronous stuff, probably return a promise
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.entries.push("c");
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

and

```
const myobject = reactive(new MyClass());
myobject.init() // `this` is a proxy inside `init`
```

Comment: Thank you! The antipattern in the constructor was actually just in the example :) In the real code I encountered this problem I defined a listener function in the constructor `this.listener = () => { this.entities.push(); }` (to be able to unsubscribe it later) and so, like you explained, "this" in the listener function referred to the original instance

Comment: In this case the workaround is to not use arrow methods and lazily bind methods, e.g. `listener` is a regular method and is used as `event => this.listener(event)` or `this.listener.bind(this)`. IIRC this is something that https://github.com/NoHomey/bind-decorator decorator can do, in case your setup supports them. The class shouldn't necessarily have hard-coded `reactive` to be used inside Vue component as another post suggests, but it needs to be designed with this concern in mind.