# Class Reactivity with Proxy does not work as expected in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, es6-proxy

I have a `Class` with a proxy-based object, the `set()` method changes another property of the same class, everything works fine if I run the code only in JS/TS.

```js
class Form {
  errors = []
  values = {}

  constructor(values) {
    this.values = new Proxy(values, {
      set: (target, prop, value) => {
        target[prop] = value

        this.errors.push('test')

        return true
      },
    })
  }
}

const form = new Form({
  name: 'Jhon',
  age: 20,
})

form.values.name = 'Maria'
form.values.age = 30

console.log(form.errors)
```

Expected result of `form.errors` is an Array like `['test', 'test']`

But if I run it inside Vue, using `{{ form.errors }}` inside `<template>` it's not reactive, it's not updated in real time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

    <div id="app">{{ form.errors }}</div>

    <script>
      class Form {
        errors = []
        values = {}

        constructor(values) {
          this.values = new Proxy(values, {
            set: (target, prop, value) => {
              target[prop] = value

              this.errors.push('test')

              return true
            },
          })
        }
      }

      const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            form: new Form({
              name: 'Jhon',
              age: 20,
            }),
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.form.values.name = 'Maria'
          this.form.values.age = 30
        },
      })

      app.mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`form.errors` is updated, but this does not reflect in Vue, it is as if Vue cannot observe these changes, the proof of this is that if we do

```js
mounted() {
  this.form.values.name = 'Maria'
  this.form.values.age = 30

  this.form.errors.push('hello')
}
```

we will have the expected result in the DOM

`['test', 'test', 'hello']`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

    <div id="app">{{ form.errors }}</div>

    <script>
      class Form {
        errors = []
        values = {}

        constructor(values) {
          this.values = new Proxy(values, {
            set: (target, prop, value) => {
              target[prop] = value

              this.errors.push('test')

              return true
            },
          })
        }
      }

      const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            form: new Form({
              name: 'Jhon',
              age: 20,
            }),
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.form.values.name = 'Maria'
          this.form.values.age = 30

          this.form.errors.push('okay')
        },
      })

      app.mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

What I want is for `form.errors` to be reactive in Vue just like any other property.

Comment: Don't capture non-reactive `this` in a callback in a constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of See the explanation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make `Form#errors` reactive in this case, initialize it with [`Vue.reactive()`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive):

```js
class Form {
  errors = Vue.reactive([])
  ⋮
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">form.errors: {{ form.errors }}</div>

    <script>
      class Form {
        errors = Vue.reactive([])
        values = {}

        constructor(values) {
          this.values = new Proxy(values, {
            set: (target, prop, value) => {
              target[prop] = value

              this.errors.push('test')

              return true
            },
          })
        }
      }

      const app = Vue.createApp({
        data() {
          return {
            form: new Form({
              name: 'Jhon',
              age: 20,
            }),
          }
        },
        mounted() {
          this.form.values.name = 'Maria'
          this.form.values.age = 30
          
          this.form.errors.push('hello')
        },
      })

      app.mount('#app')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```