# How to make reactivity work with a Promise started from a constructor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, vuejs3

I have a class `Thing`, whose constructor starts an asynchronous `fetch` operation. When the `fetch` completes, the result is assigned to a field on the `Thing` object:

```
  class Thing {
    constructor() {
      this.image = null
      this.load()
    }

    async load() {
      const response = await fetch('https://placekitten.com/200/300')
      const blob = await response.blob()
      this.image = await createImageBitmap(blob)
    }
  }
```

I'm using `thing.image` in a `Vue` component. The problem is that Vue doesn't pick up on the change in `image` when the `Promise` resolves. I think I understand why this happens: in the constructor, `this` refers to the raw `Thing`, and not Vue's reactive proxy wrapper. So the assignment to `this.image` ends up bypassing the proxy.

It works if I move the `load` call out of the constructor, so that `this` inside the `load` function refers to the reactive proxy. But that makes my `Thing` class harder to use.

Is there a better way to handle this issue?

Minimal example ([Vue playground link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)):

```
<script setup>
  import { reactive } from 'vue'

  class Thing {
    constructor() {
      this.image = null
      this.load() // This does not trigger reactivity.
    }

    async load() {
      const response = await fetch('https://placekitten.com/200/300')
      const blob = await response.blob()
      this.image = await createImageBitmap(blob)
    }
  }

  const thing = reactive(new Thing())
  // thing.load() // This triggers reactivity as expected.
</script>

<template>
  <p v-if="thing.image">
    Image size is {{thing.image.width}}×{{thing.image.height}}
  </p>
  <p v-if="!thing.image">
    Loading...
  </p>
</template>
```

Comment: I think the Ref doesn't call the constructor it just take the values and bind them to new object so we have to call them manually  [Ref source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/cdd2df6171963096abb94600987f1706e40d2ab6/src/core/observer/index.ts#L131)

Comment: @raghavapatnam I am not actually using `ref` in my actual code, but probably `reactive` under the hood (the object is assigned to the component's `data`). I just edited the example; sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Technically with JavaScript standard load function should be executed but with Vue reactive / ref - they seem to return only object

Comment: It's generally an antipattern to do async side effects in a constructor that you can't control. Especially because it doesn't play well with classes that are unaware of Vue reactivity

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue 3 reactivity not triggered from inside a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your class attribute as a ref

```js
<script setup>
  import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'

  class Thing {
    constructor() {
      this.image = ref(null)
      this.load()
    }

    async load() {
      const response = await fetch('https://placekitten.com/200/300')
      const blob = await response.blob()
      this.image.value = await createImageBitmap(blob)
    }
  }

  const thing = reactive(new Thing())
  // thing.load() // This triggers reactivity as expected.
</script>

<template>
  <p v-if="thing.image">
    Image size is {{thing.image.width}}×{{thing.image.height}}
  </p>
  <p v-if="!thing.image">
    Loading...
  </p>
</template>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked, thanks! Caveat: when going through the reactive proxy object, `this.image` is no longer a `Ref`, but instead resolves automatically to the actual value. Even inside methods on `Thing`!

Comment: ref are automatically unwrapped when accessing from a reactive, object: 
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html#ref-unwrapping-in-reactive-objects

Comment: Yeah. This means that `this.load()` works when called from within the constructor, but `thing.load()` will no longer work, because `this.image.value` is undefined. Something to be aware of!

Comment: Yes because the load function as been proxied, you can retrieve the original object and use the load method on it by using toRaw:

  `const thing = reactive(new Thing())
  const rawThing = toRaw(thing)
  rawThing.load()`

Comment: `rawThing.load()` is doable but smells fishy. This indicates the fundamental problem, this.load() shouldn't have been called inside the constructor in the first place, just because this makes class act weird, even with the explicit use of reactivity api