# Vue 3 external state reactivity

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, reactive

I have a pattern I use to try to keep as much logic (unit tests, data fetching, etc.) in vanilla js and use Vue to handle the rendering or any other functionality only possible in the framework. That way my app is as framework agnostic as possible.

I have a project that has progressed over the last few years in Vue 2 to Vue 2.6 and the composition api.  Essentially: I have a vanilla js objects then expose them via another "useMyObject" style function and set the state to reactive.  I then bind all actions everything to my "vanilla" js controller and bind the template to the reactive state.  In vue 2.6 + compostion, this has worked seemlessly.

I have trivialised the following, but as an example:

```
// Vanilla JS file nick-controller.ts
export interface Person {
  id: number
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  address: {
    line1: string
    line2: string
    city: string
    state: string
    zip: string
  }
}

export interface NickControllerState {
  people: Person[]
  personEditing: Person
  isoTimeStamp: string
}

export function factoryNickController() {
    const state: NickControllerState = {
    people: [],
    personEditing: {
      id: 0,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: '',
      age: 0,
      address: {
        line1: '',
        line2: '',
        city: '',
        state: '',
        zip: ''
      }
    },
    isoTimeStamp: ''
  }

  function addPerson(person: Person) {
    state.people.push(person)
    state.isoTimeStamp = new Date().toISOString()
  }

  return {
    state,
    addPerson
  }
}
```

Then the file to make reactive (I have added "addTestPerson" just for my hair pulling testing, but usually this file is only a few lines long)

```
export function useNickController() {
  const controller = factoryNickController()

  // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  // * * * Make the vanilla js state reactive. * * *
  // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  // * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  const state = reactive(controller.state)

  function addTestPerson() {
    addPersonCounter++

    //  create random 5 digit number
    const random5DigitNumber = Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 90000)

    const person: Person = {
      id: addPersonCounter,
      firstName: 'Nick_' + addPersonCounter.toString(),
      lastName: 'Benz_' + addPersonCounter.toString(),
      age: 50,
      address: {
        line1: '123 Main St',
        line2: '',
        city: 'Denver',
        state: 'CO',
        zip: random5DigitNumber.toString()
      }
    }
    controller.addPerson(person)
  }

  return {
    state,
    controller,
    addTestPerson,
  }
}
```

Then create a single file component, add in the "useFunction"...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="nickController.addTestPerson()">Add</button>

    <ul v-for="person in nickController.state.people" :key="person.id">
      <li>id: {{ person.id + person.firstName + '-' + person.lastName }}</li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, type SetupContext } from 'vue'
import { useNickController } from '@/modules/nick/useNickController'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'NickTestControllerPage',
  components: {},
  props: {},
  setup(props: any, context: SetupContext) {
    let nickController = useNickController()

    return { nickController }
  }
})
</script>
```

Push the add button or change the state in any way, template re-renders...perfect.

I'm now involved in a Vue 3 project, if I use the above method in a "defineComponent" SFC or use the Vue preferred "setup" method...

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useNickController } from '@/modules/nick/useNickController'
import {
  factoryNickController,
  type NickControllerState,
  type Person
} from '@/modules/nick/nick-controller'
import { reactive} from 'vue'

const nickController = useNickController()


function addTestPerson() {
  //  create random 5 digit number
  const random5DigitNumber = Math.floor(10000 + Math.random() * 90000)
  ...etc...etc...
  nickController.state.people.push(person)
}
</script>
```

...it will not update until the "next tick" render.  E.g. stick an input field on the page bound to some local variable...

```
const myField = ref("")
```

...change the field value, triggers a re-render...then the v-for in my reactive vanila state is rendered.

I have tried everything differnt method I can think of: computed, watchers, vanilla object in the component...I can't get it to work.

To re-iterate: in vue 2.6 + composition api, this works perfectly.

Any help or pointers would be gladly welcomed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth it to keep code framework-agnostic in this manner, as it's framework-aware in fact. You have to always keep in mind how it will play along with reactivity api and jump through hoops to fit a framework. This makes sense when you can integrate it with multiple frameworks, but if you use Vue alone an additional abstraction layer just creates an additional point of failure without real benefits, that you've got this problem is the actual proof

Answer (score 0):

Vue 2 modifies an object in order to make reactive according and adds getter/setter pairs for existing properties, as explained in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html), `reactive` has to use this mechanism in 2.7 composition API. Vue 3 wraps an object with `Proxy` and leaves original object intact.

This is [common pitfall with reactive classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance/67895251#67895251) in Vue. Despite the example doesn't use classes, the problem is the same; a reference to non-reactive original object is kept and modified, and the changes cannot be tracked. The solution is the same as well, reactive state should be referred consistently, the most straightforward way is use `this` instead of non-reactive `state` variable:

```
  ...
  return {
    state,
    addPerson(person: Person) {
      // this.state !== state in Vue 3
      this.state.people.push(person)
      this.state.isoTimeStamp = new Date().toISOString()
    }
  }
  ...
```

When a method is defined this way, `this` TS type is properly inferred.

And used like:

```
const controller = reactive(factoryNickController());
```

The difference is that `addPerson(...)` instead of `controller.addPerson(...)` will result in wrong context, methods need to be rebound in order to allow this usage.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two ways to make a vanilla object reactive

1. By changing all pointers to it to its reactive variant

```
class A {
   list = [1, 2, 3];
   double(){
      for (let i of this.list.keys()) this.list[i] *= 2'
   }
}
let a = new A()
a.list = reactive(a.list)
watch(a.list, console.log)
a.double() // logs
```

2. By making the instance or protorype reactive

```
// all instances of A will be reactive
class A {
  constructor(){ return reactive(this) }
}
// I don't remember if this works
let o = Object.setPrototypeOf({
   a: 123
}, reactive({}))
```