# How to make external state reactive with Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, state

I have a scenario where some state is managed by an external JavaScript library. I want this external state to become reactive to use it e.g. in the template. The state changes in the background based on some conditions (e.g. when network connectivity changes).

For the sake of this question let's pretend the `Counter.val` should displayed on the template. `Counter.increment` is responsible for changing the state. In my scenario `Counter.increment` will never be called by my app.

```
class Counter {
  _val = 0;

  get val() { return this._val }

  increment() { this._val++ } 
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Using the usual `ref`, `reactive` methods
   After calling `Counter.increment` those do not change, because the invocation happens on the vanilla `Counter`, not the proxied/wrapped `ref`/`reactive.
2. The Vue docs [suggest `shallowRef`](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#integration-with-external-state-systems) for external state, but mention

   > When the external state changes, replace the ref value to trigger updates.

   I do not know when the external changes and I do not want to poll `Counter.val`.

I've prepared [an example](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9k01v2zAMhv8KoUtTNHBS9NY5wbaihw7YB7YcBQyewiRqbcqQqDSA4f8+Wv5IDkUOCSy+j8iXpN2oL3WdHSOqR5UH423NEJBjvdZkq9p5hgY87uZgXFVHxu0cHH13keQRWth5V8GN3L/RpMmURQjwlFQPjaa/x6KEFSw/dSrskUECs9uUk6Mn4IMNWaLahFgyHiskTtCk3t1JLU3CGEeBwUhSwvex1Ox2EngrkhiemXOsgyQ6djCT3Kt1h2aSOmL3L/CIs63EfJ+EYtlLU8/DZekNJGHHC+cxHOTGhQR9mqGAJUK/wVNy0cV6RAa9EcpFng1J5nC/XC6lIgzzuMa08ssX/dJkXXJgrOqyYJQTQH64XzfN0H3b5gs5D/HO80qrZFGr9Vn6F5kdwWdTWvMmhBHr00KEfCGTL3pILuSLqaCaKw4yj53dZ6/BkbxOaQ6SQqZuS/Q/a7YyL60exwlpVZSle/+WYuwjzse4OaB5+yD+Gk5dTKtfMgj0R9Rq0rjw8n718vOfHzLsC7Fy21gKfUX8jcGVsfPYY18jbcX2BZfcvqSPwtJ+E55PjBTGpjqjaW+J10q+iacrrZ/tPmQPw75b1f4HAb8w4A==) including the counter.

Comment: Consider addressing your real case instead of made-up scenario because the answer may differ and be applicable specifically to that external library. Reactive classes have several pitfalls in Vue. In this specific example it should have been done like `const c = reactive(new Counter())` but it could fail in other situation

Comment: The real scenario is that someone calls `increment` behind your back. It does not change with the real library, despite making the question harder to answer because you would not only need to know Vue but also ASP.NET Core SignalR.

Comment: In case you're able to inject `c` somewhere then that's it. If you don't control the way Counter is implemented or instantiated then things may go wrong, that's the sum-up https://stackoverflow.com/a/77062978/3731501