vue 3 can't listen to class object responses
I am a vue3 beginner, I use another class in my code, I want to make the instantiated object responsive, what should I do?
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

class View {
 time = 0;
  constructor() {
    this.setTime()
  }
  setTime() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date().getTime()
    }, 2000)
  }
}
const state = ref(new View())
</script>

<template>
  <h1>
    state {{ state.time }}</h1>
</template>


This is an example code, state.time cannot be reactive.
But when I add other responsive variables, the view can be updated again, as shown in the following code:
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

class View {
 time = 0;
  constructor() {
    this.setTime()
  }
  setTime() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.time = new Date().getTime()
    }, 1000)
  }
}
const state = ref(new View())

const _state = ref(0)
setInterval(() => {
  _state.value = new Date().getTime()
}, 1000)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>
    state {{ state.time }}</h1>
    
  <h1>
    _state {{ _state }}</h1>
</template>

this confuses me
state.time cannot be reactive.

because new Date().getTime() is not a reactive dependency

you are not using ref correctly, check the documentation https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894487/vue-3-reactivity-not-triggered-from-inside-a-class-instance . Avoid reactive classes, especially if you're a beginner, they are quirky and their use can be rarely justified

because the const state = ref(new View()) dosen't link the View Class and ref.
you can try the toRefs like const state = toRefs(new View()).
